# What is the equivalent in metal of glClearStencil(AStencil)

Tags: objective-c, metal, metalkit

What is the equivalent in metal of `glClearStencil(AStencil)`? glClearStencil specifies the index used by glClear to clear the stencil buffer. s is masked with 2 m - 1 , where m is the number of bits in the stencil buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [stencil value](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlrenderpassstencilattachmentdescriptor/1437931-clearstencil?language=objc) to use when the stencil render target is cleared.
If the loadAction property of the render target is set to MTLLoadActionClear, then at the start of a render pass, the contents of the texture are filled with the value stored in the clearStencil property. Otherwise, clearStencil is ignored.

The default value is 0.